# Is NaN a comparable type in golang?

Tags: go

I came across a golang quiz which used NaN as a maps key and it ran without any error. If map's keys are supposed to be comparable is NaN a comparable type or is this a compiler bug which allowed NaN as a key.

Here's the [quiz source](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1572422894613045248), the [go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/fF8JKNQw8k1) and code below.

```
package main

var x = 0.0

func main() {
  var a = x / x // a = NaN
  var m = map[float64]int{a: 1}
  m[a] = 2
  for k := range m {
  delete(m, k)
  }
  println(len(m)) // prints 2
}
```

Comment: See [issue 20660](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20660)

Comment: In general, NaN is a special float (like infinity or negative zero). Floats are comparable, so NaN is comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that this is not a compiler bug.

Maps require comparable *types* as keys.  Float (regardless of float32 or float64) is a *comparable type*.  What's odd about NaN (and in a different way, zero, which can be either positive or negative zero) is that while you can compare two NaNs, they always compare as unequal.  So some float value `x` is not equal to itself when `x` is NaN.  This produces surprises.

[Issue 20660](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20660) comments note that the same kind of problems occur in a number of other languages.

[I particularly like Russ Cox's comment that there are only bad answers here.](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20660#issuecomment-887917856)

Answer (score 3):

Any float64 is comparable. There is no problem comparing any two floats. You can compare a NaN to 3.141 or NaN to NaN.

The problem is not compar**ability** of NaNs/floats. The problem is that *any* comparison of a NaN with *anything*, even an other NaN or itself will result in false.

```
   NaN != x   for all  x, including NaN
```

This makes using NaNs as map keys basically impossible because it's impossible to find a NaN.